# How to find a representative image from HTML with Nokogiri in Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, xslt, xpath, nokogiri

I need to move away from using xsltproc command-line tools for deployment on Heroku, since they don't really support it. The Nokogiri gem looks like it should work for everything I need, although I am having trouble finding a representative image from HTML.

What I mean by representative image is, the first of all images under /html/body that have "://" in the link and don't have "ads." or "ad." or "?" in the link. Is there a Nokogiri function that will do this, possibly returning an array of all images, and I can filter them how I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following XPath should select the image that meets your stated criteria:

```
/html/body//img[@src[contains(.,'://') 
                     and not(contains(.,'ads.') 
                             or contains(.,'ad.') 
                             or contains(.,'?')
                            )
                     ]
                ][1]
```

You can use it like this:

```
doc.xpath("/html/body//img[@src[contains(.,'://') 
       and not(contains(.,'ads.') or contains(.,'ad.') or contains(.,'?'))]][1]")
```

Comment: Using single quotes gave me an error, but double quotes around `doc.xpath("/html...[1]")` worked. Also, having the [1] inside didn't seem to make a difference. I used [0] on the outside. If anyone wants to know, the way to get to the image link is:

`doc.xpath(...)[0]["src"]`

Comment: Whoops, should have wrapped the XPath expression with double quotes. I've updated the answer. As for the `[0]`, I don't know much about the Nokogirl api, but that shouldn't work for XPath. XPath uses 1 based indexes, not 0-based. The syntax `[1]` is short for `[position()=1]`, and there is no item who's `position()` is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need to read about [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/Xpath/). Here is a pretty good (and simple) [tutorial](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/getting-started-with-nokogiri/).